# unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d79ed0

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates

I am using delegate to get an option that user choosed in a table view but I constantly receive a error like below:

2012-05-12 23:26:06.704 test[4629:fb03] -[AddContentViewController catPickViewController:didSelectGame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d79ed0

I logged the option in the table view and can't log it in my first view.

This is what I have at the table view

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if (selectedIndex != NSNotFound)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0]];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    NSString *theGame = [games objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@",theGame);
    [self.delegate catPickViewController:self didSelectGame:theGame];

}
```

and this is what I have for the select method:

```
- (void)CatPickViewController:(CatPickViewController *)controller didSelectGame:(NSString *)theGame
{
    NSLog(@"%@",theGame);
    category = theGame;
    self.catDetails.text = category;

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I knew the problem is with  [self.delegate catPickViewController:self didSelectGame:theGame];

but what shall I do with it?

I forgot to mention that I have catPickViewController.h like

```
@class CatPickViewController;

@protocol CatPickViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)catPickViewController:(CatPickViewController *)controller didSelectGame:(NSString *)game;
@end

@interface CatPickViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CatPickViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *game;

@end
```

so catPickViewController as you guys mentioned is from here

Comment: method signatures almost NEVER begin with a capital letter.

Comment: Just before calling `catPickViewController` (near the bottom of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`) log the value of `self.delegate` and see what it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `catPickViewController`, but the method name is spelled `CatPickViewController`. You should change that to `catPickViewController`.

Comment: I edit the question and as you can see it's not what you think,catPickViewController do exist

Comment: where is that method defined, in CatPickViewController or AddContentViewController?

Comment: In the text you have posted now, you still have the method implementation under `- (void)CatPickViewController:(CatPickViewController *)controller didSelectGame:(NSString *)theGame`. This doesn't match the declaration in your header file.